# How do I find the fourth Kartana if I accidentally knocked it out previously?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Recently, I was trying to catch the ultra beast Kartana, but ended up fainting one by accident. Now, I've caught three, but can't find the fourth one. How can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep looking. They will continue spawning until you caught 4. If you want to be sure, turn on the music and compare it to the usual score of the location you're looking in. You might want to try the alternate location, too: Kartana can be found on Route 17 as well as in Malie Garden.

Comment: Thank u but ive been running all over route 17 but there was never any of them im malie garden

Comment: Did you check the music? If you're unsure what it's supposed to be, look for YouTube videos of the area you're looking in under normal conditions and compare it to what you hear. Also, just to be sure, have you talked to Looker to confirm there's one missing?